# Java Client/Server turn based help

Tags: java, client-server

I am trying to make a client/server turn based game.  I want this to be a 2 player game.  I will be using a Java applet as the client so that people can play online through a browser.

What I know so far is that I can create a server that accepts all incoming connections and create a thread to handle clients that connect.  I can also write the client that will connect to the server.  What I don't know is how to get two separate clients to interact with each other.

Applets cannot talk to each other so communication must be done via the server/threads (I assume).

I am not new to Java, but I have never done any networking before.  Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the best strategy to approach a turn based game such as this, is to decide on some basic architectural approaches.  Diagram out the componenents and some basic game flow diagrams.

You should put the bulk of the game engine logic in the server component.  The clients should be kept as thin as possible, focusing primarily on

1. Communication with the game engine
2. Accepting user inputs
3. Interpreting game engine responses
4. Drawing the screens

Your server/game engine should be relatively stateless, yet maintain a list of current game sessions in play.  Stateful SOAP web services or even HTTP Servlets would be a good choice because they maintain session for you by placing and reading session cookies in the request.

Everything web works on request response so it is by nature stateless, but certain technologies like Java servlets will help you maintain sessions so that you don't have to.  No need for physically creating seperate threads, each request causes the application server to spawn a new thread of execution, while the session by nature is volatile.

On the server side I would persist all data for a particular active game in the session.  In this way, your game engine will maintain the orderly communication between the two players.

1. Player 1 sends end of turn request with all of the game state change information.
2. Game engine interprets request, makes necessary changes to the game state.
3. Player 2 sends frequent requests to check and see if it is Player 2s turn yet.
4. Game engine acknowledges Player 2 request for its turn and sends the new game state in response.
5. Player 2 receives the response, updates its copy of the game state making note of the changes since its last turn.
6. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Most of what you said makes sense, im just a little confused as to where the servlets would come into play.

Comment: Servlets play the role of the server essentially.  They are requested for information or information is posted to it.  It is necessary because the applets can not talk to each other directly.  Think along the lines of playing Starcraft on Battle.NET.  There are many players in a single session/game and Battle.NET is the server.  Each player is constantly sending information about what they are doing to Battle.NET and in response Battle.NET sends updated information about other players.  Don't confuse the server and the host. The host is just a player who initializes the params of the session.

Comment: This is pretty heavy stuff so don't get discouraged.  Before you delve into a servlet and what it is capable of you need a FIRM grasp of HTTP communications.  There are countless tutorials online to teach you this.  When you understand that paradigm you can delve into making simple servlets, ie request a web page, return HTML response.  Then you can get into more advanced servlets like serializing a Java object into an HTTP request, and deserializing a Java object from a servlet HTTP response.

Comment: Ok, to clarify how this needs to work:

Client (Game applet):
Step 1:  Send connection request to the server
Step 2:  Connection is accepted by server then requests game info from servlet.
Step 3:  Based on info from the servlet, client does whatever task is neccessary.
Step 4:  Client starts the cycle of asking the servlet for info again.

Server:
Step 1:  Start and listen to particular port
Step 2:  Accepts connection, saves the connection info, then resumes listening to the port.

Game Servlet:
Step 1: Does whatever the game applet tells it to and sends back a response.

Comment: After writing all that it seems im more lost than I thought.  I think its worth noting that when a user logs into the applet via a login screen they will have options for either creating a game or joining a game that was created by another player.

Comment: The servlet and the server are virtually the same thing.  A typical "server" would be Apache Tomcat which can be known as an application server or a servlet container.  You configure Tomcat to listen on a port for HTTP communication, that will be done for you.  I strongly feel that you should go here and download the latest version of Tomcat, http://tomcat.apache.org/ and play around with some of the Hello World servlet samples that come bundled with it.  These will give ideas about how a browser communicates with a servlet, and then it should be cake to write a simple applet to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You just use the server as a middle-man.

1. Client A sends (writes) message to Server with attribute denoting Client B as destination
2. Server receives (reads) the message and forwards (writes) the message to Client B
3. Client B receives (reads) the message.