# Online poker game in Java

Tags: java, javascript, client-server

I have to implement a multiplayer poker game which can play only by two players. I have to use java. And it should be a online game. What i want want to know is how to communicate between these two players. I mean what kind of methods and technologies i have to refer ? Can someone please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650465/java-client-server-turn-based-help?rq=1

Comment: Check the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) and [this site](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/) for an idea of how to get a program to communicate with another program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think of a server and two client apps. That requires knowledge about sockets, serversockets.   Basically a socket is a connection, you use it to communicate with server.

There is a good explanation of sockets in the Java Head First 2nd edition book, there you are taught to make something similar to a chat app.

You need a server socket on your server, that listens for connections(you will need threading there), and a socket on your client, via which you send messages to the server.